# Warped T1-11 siding, can this be nailed back in?

Tags: siding

I have a section of T1-11 siding that is warped slightly (see picture). I am tempted to just hammer this back in, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. What's the proper way to fix this kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: Is this below the area of the crack t111 from your earlier post? If this is below you may have some serious problems causing the delamanation and this bowing that need to be checked before we could properly advise.

Comment: @EdBeal no, the crack is on the east side, this warping is on the south side. These are the only two spots where anything is out of whack. I'm trying to decide if it's safe to try and nail this back down, or whether rot risk would be too high.

Comment: It looks like it was nailed well my concern would be what caused the bulge. I probably would probably give it a try with 8 penny ring shank nails since they hold better than standard galvanized.

Comment: Without knowing what caused the warp (poor water run off from above) its hard to tell if rot will happen. Rather than nail, might I suggest a deck screw? This will hold better than a nail and if this does seem to get worse, its easier to remove the screw.

Comment: @JeffCates I don't think a screw would help, I tried nailing it down and the part that cracked and stuck out felt pretty weak, the hammer when right through it. I think I will need to replace that section of the siding.

Comment: That sounds like water damaged siding. I would look above that area and see if there is proper drainage from the roof. Eliminate the future replacement of the siding.